# Reading multiple handwritten digits with keras CNN model

Tags: python, image, keras, conv-neural-network, digits

I've built a CNN for digit recognition using some of the data provided by the crohme data set. It is trained on > 200 000 images and should recognize the digits 0 - 9 and also +, -, =, (, ) because this project's goal is to read a simple equation and then calculate the result. This means that I'm feeding images containing **multiple digits / arithmetic operators** to a function that will then cut out square bits and have the keras model predict it.

These images can look like this for example:

[image: simple equation as input]

The result I get for this image is `results:  ['1', '1', '-', '1']`. So it got the - right but the rest is terribly wrong. For the 1s it predicted the network is 59 %, 76 % and 57 % sure.

Naturally, the square bits I cut out don't always show the digit in a perfectly centered way and I understand why this is difficult to predict correctly. But the first digit for example was pretty well cut out and still incorrectly predicted.

So my issues are:

1. **individual more or less well displayed digits / operators aren't well recognized.** When I try it with test images from the data set the network gets 99 % right so it must be an image preparation issue.
2. **Can you help me improve my function *partial_img_rec* that is in control over the cutting of the square parts that will then be passed on to the keras model?** These parts all have the size of the original picture's height and they move on the the right depending on whether a digit has been predicted with a probability of at least 40%. If so, I move on 80% of the square's width and if not I take smaller steps. It's a recursive function that moves on until it reaches the right end of the image.

I've asked a similar question before what the issue of photos of individual digits is concerned and I got some useful advise about the way a digit is centered in a picture. Please note that I don't have that much control about this when I've got a picture containing multiple digits.

This is my code:

```
# import keras
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dropout
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import model_from_json
#from keras.utils import np_utils
# numpy is necessary since keras uses numpy arrays
import numpy as np

# imports for pictures
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import PIL
#import cv2

# imports for tests
import random
import os    
class neuralNetwork():

        def prepare_image(self, img, show = False):
            """ prepares the training and testing as well as
                the partial images used in partial_img_rec by transforming them
                into numpy arrays that the network will be able to process """

            # convert to greyscale
            img = img.convert("L")
            # rescale image to 45 * 45 dimension if neccessary
            if img.size != (45,45):
                img = img.resize((45,45), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)

            # transform to vector
            img = np.asarray(img, "float32")
            img = img / 255.
            # threshold eliminates background noise
            img[img < 0.1] = 0.

            if show:
                plt.imshow(img, cmap = "Greys")
            img = img.reshape((1, 45, 45, 1))

            return img


        def __init__(self, newModel = False):
            """ initialized the neural network either by creating and training a new model or by loading a saved one """
            # paths to data
            self.train_data = ".//train"
            self.test_data = ".//test"

            self.test_img, self.test_res = self.prepare_data(self.test_data)


            """ The following code is based on existing code that can be found on the following websites :
                https://machinelearningmastery.com/handwritten-digit-recognition-using-convolutional-neural-networks-python-keras/
                and https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-keras-deep-learning-models/
            """

            num_classes = 15
            """ This is a CNN (Convolutional Neural Network) which is more efficient than the standard NN """
            if newModel or not os.path.exists("model.json") or not os.path.exists("model.h5"):
                # only load test data if needed
                self.train_img, self.train_res = self.prepare_data(self.train_data, shuffle = True)
                print("creating new model")
                # create a new model
                self.model = Sequential()
                self.model.add(Conv2D(30, (5, 5), input_shape=(45, 45, 1), activation='relu'))
                self.model.add(MaxPooling2D())
                self.model.add(Conv2D(15, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
                self.model.add(MaxPooling2D())
                self.model.add(Dropout(0.2))
                self.model.add(Flatten())
                self.model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
                self.model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
                self.model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
                #compile model
                self.model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
                # train the model
                self.model.fit(self.train_img, self.train_res, validation_data=(self.test_img, self.test_res), epochs=10, batch_size=64, verbose=2)

                # save model for later use
                model_json = self.model.to_json()
                with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
                    json_file.write(model_json)
                # save weights
                self.model.save_weights("model.h5")
                print("Saved trained model to disk")
            else:
               # load the model from disk
               json_file = open("model.json", "r")
               loaded_model = json_file.read()
               json_file.close()
               self.model = model_from_json(loaded_model)
               # load weights from disk
               self.model.load_weights("model.h5")
               #compile model
               self.model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
               print("Loaded model and weights from disk")



        def predict_result(self, img, show = False):
            """ predicts the number in a picture (vector) """
            assert type(img) == np.ndarray and img.shape == (1, 45, 45, 1)
            # 1, 45, 45, 1 is the image shape the input layer demands. 45, 45 are the dimensions and 1 stands for greyscale (channel)

            if show:
                img = img.reshape((45, 45))
                # show the picture
                plt.imshow(img, cmap='Greys')
                plt.show()
                img = img.reshape((1, 45, 45, 1))

            # the probabilities
            res_probabilities = self.model.predict(img)
            # the value with the hightest probability
            res_number = np.argmax(res_probabilities)

            return (list(self.assignments.keys())[list(self.assignments.values()).index(res_number)], res_probabilities.tolist()[0])    # we only need the first dimension since the array only has one



        def partial_img_rec(self, image, upper_left, lower_right, results=[], show = True):
            """ passes square parts of images to predict_result """
            left_x, left_y = upper_left
            right_x, right_y = lower_right

            print("current test part: ", upper_left, lower_right)
            print("results: ", results)
            # condition to stop recursion: we've reached the full width of the picture
            width, height = image.size
            if right_x > width:
                return results

            partial = image.crop((left_x, left_y, right_x, right_y))
            if show:
                partial.show()
            partial = self.prepare_image(partial)

            # is there a number or operator in this part of the image? 
            res, prop = self.predict_result(partial)
            print("result: ", res, ". probabilities: ", prop)
            # only count this result if the network is at least 40% sure
            if prop[self.assignments[res]] >= 0.4:        
                results.append(res)
                # step is 80% of the partial image's size (which is equivalent to the original image's height) 
                step = int(height * 0.8)
                print("found valid result")
            else:
                # if there is no number or operator found we take smaller steps
                step = height // 20 
            print("step: ", step)
            # recursive call with modified positions ( move on step variables )
            return self.partial_img_rec(image, (left_x + step, left_y), (right_x + step, right_y), results = results)

        def individual_digits(self, img):
            """ uses partial_img_rec to predict individual digits in square images """
            assert type(img) == PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile or type(img) == PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile or type(img) == PIL.Image.Image
            if img.size[0]  != img.size[1]:
                    print(img, " has the wrong proportions: ", img.size,". It has to be a square.")
            return self.partial_img_rec(img, (0,0), (img.size[0], img.size[1]), results=[])


        def multiple_digits(self, imgName):
            """ takes as input an image without unnecessary whitespace surrounding the digits """
            assert type(imgName) == str
            #img = cuttingImage(imgName)
            img = PIL.Image.open(imgName)

            width, height = img.size
            # start with the first square part of the image. This can work because there is no unneccessary whitespace.
            res_list = self.partial_img_rec(img, (0,0),(height ,height), results = [])
            res_str = ""
            for elem in res_list:
                res_str += str(elem)
            return res_str
```

These are the assignments:

```
                                    {
                                    "0" : 0,
                                    "1" : 1,
                                    "2" : 2,
                                    "3" : 3,
                                    "4" : 4,
                                    "5" : 5,
                                    "6" : 6,
                                    "7" : 7,
                                    "8" : 8,
                                    "9" : 9,
                                    "-" : 10,
                                    "+" : 11,
                                    "=" : 12,
                                    "(" : 13,
                                    ")" : 14
                                    }
```

If you want to try it with my network please note that I left out some of the data preparation like the one-hot-encoding for better readability. Also you can get the two files containing the trained model [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1h1HQJItJ2GIc4L9AD9l5xybnVv9cmLaA?usp=sharing).

Comment: Have you solved the issue? I'm curious about result

Comment: @Farhad Nope. It was for a college project and my results turned out to be good enough. I'd still like to know what was going wrong but well - had to move on. Do you have a similar issue ?